# AngularJS passing data issue with param that contains a period

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

So I have a fully functional service layer built with angular 1 and ES2015, is it a common issue to have a period in the param name, I tried making it a string param, but still nothing is working properly.

```
someService.getProjects(
{CustomerID: customerID, 
'pagination.sortStyle': paginationStyle 
}).then(response => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response.data))
}
,function (response) {
     alert(response.data)
});
```

Where you see `pagination.sortStyle`, that is where its not liking it... Any ideas, as I have to use `pagination.sortStyle` in the GET.

Comment: what does "it's not liking it" mean, exactly? can you post the error text?

Comment: if possible, show us how someService.getProjects handle the provided parameter. for instance, if i stringify the object it gets the correct output, however if the service tries to do a "smart translation" on the property an error might occur

Comment: The CustomerID and the stringified pagination.sortstyle are the params, if I remove the quotes around it I get unexpected token, obviously. So banging my head on this issue. What do you mean by smart translation? Can you tell me a bit more about that.

Comment: Well, it appeared the way I was building the $http get was wrong on a different service layer, issue is now resolved, thanks for the help. I will post the rest of the code in a little bit and how I solved the issue.